# replaceObjectAtIndex objectforKey crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsmutablearray

I want to replace content of my array with some other value,

Here is my Array value:

```
    [Arr objectAtIndex:i] =  "End_Date" = "31 Mar 2014";
                             "Merchant_Category_Id" = 162;
                             "Merchant_ID" = 1262;
                             "Merchant_Name" = Mp;
                             "Merchant_SmallImage" = "http://abcdm/imge/cb256.jpg";
                             "Voucher_Id" = 130510;
                             "Voucher_Name" = "Rs 555 OFF";
                              favStatus = 0;
```

**What i want to do is, i want to update the favStatus from `0` to `1` at index `i`**

Here is my code snippet i have tried,

```
[Arr replaceObjectAtIndex:[[[Arr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"favStatus"] integerValue] withObject:@"1"];
```

every time it returns value `0` when i Log `[[[Arr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"favStatus"] integerValue]`

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the crash message please.?

Comment: [Arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"1"]; Try this

Comment: `Crash Error` : "&exd" = "NSRangeException\nTrace:\n-[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]\n-[CRIndCategPgViewController AddToFav:]\n-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:w";

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya: what about `objectForKey` ? i want to update the key called `favStatus`

Comment: You can go with Anoop Vaidya's approach. You are trying replace the dictionary with a string.

Comment: @Krunal show my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing entire object (dictionary) with a string @"0".

In fact you can to create a new tempDictionary, and extract the keyValue of @"favStatus". Replace it and then put the new object in the array as :

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [[Arr objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];
[tempDictionary setValue:@"0" forKey:@"favStatus"];

 [Arr replaceObjectAtIndex: i
                withObject: tempDictionary];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *yourDictionary = [[Arr objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];
[yourDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"favStatus"];
[yourDictionary setValue:@"0" forKey:@"favStatus"];

[Arr replaceObjectAtIndex: i
               withObject: yourDictionary];
```

i hope this code usefull for you.

Comment: No need to remove any key!!! As if you add a new value with same key, the older value is removed.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya okay . i don't know about that

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [[Arr objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];
[tempDictionary setValue:@"1" forKey:@"favStatus"];

[Arr replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:tempDictionary];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty strange looking. Are the elements of your array `NSMutableDictionaries`? If so,  you could update `favStatus` at index `i` with `arr[i][@"favStatus"] = @1;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I am giving it as an example

**Taking an array and adding dictionaries.**

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"karun%d",i] forKey:@"Merchant_Name"];
    [dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"favStatus"];

    [arr addObject:dict];

}

NSLog(@"Before Replace : %@",arr.description);
```

**Now I am going to replace all the dictionaries favStatus value to 1**

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.count;i++){

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = (NSMutableDictionary*)[arr objectAtIndex:i];
    [dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"favStatus"];

}

NSLog(@"After Replace : %@",arr.description);
```

Hope this helps :)